# composer: replace dependencies with local versions

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to use a library that defines some extensive dependencies in its `composer.json` file, even though it only uses one or two small classes of those dependencies.

Is it possible to set up my require in a way that composer thinks I already have those dependencies and lets me use some self-defined minimal mock classes instead?

Example: I want package `lib/a` which in turn requires `lib/b`.

Normally I would have something like this in my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
  "lib/a": "^2.2"
}
```

I thought that maybe 'provide' would fool composer:

```
"require": {
  "lib/a": "^2.2"
},
"provide": {
  "lib/b": "2.2.0"
}
```

But it seems to do nothing. Composer still downloads `lib/b`.

Is there any way to tell composer to ignore a certain dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `replace` does what I want:

```
"require": {
  "lib/a": "^2.2"
},
"replace": {
  "lib/b": "*"
}
```

This tells composer that the package at hand replaces any version of `lib/b`